# ASP.NET Core Serilog does not output logs by "Rolling interval Day"

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, logging, serilog

I'm having issues getting Serilog to generate log files that have a rolling interval of Day (one Log file per day until size limit is reached). I'm using Serilog ASP.NET Core and Serilog Slinks packages. The strange thing is that it seems to work fine when I run the solution on IIS Express. However it doesn't work properly when the solution is actually Published.

[image: Log file output]

See below for my Serilog configuration in appsettings.json file.

```
  "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": "Warning",
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "C:\\Users\\MyUser\\Documents\\Logs\\MyService_Logs_.txt",
          "rollingInterval": "Day",
          "fileSizeLimitBytes": 5000000,
          "rollOnFileSizeLimit": true,
          "retainedFileCountLimit": 40,
          "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss.fff} [{Level:u3}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}"
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "Console",
        "outputTemplate": "==> {Timestamp:HH:mm:ss.fff} [{Level:u3}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}"

      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Any tips or suggestions from anyone on how to go about troubleshooting this? Would really appreciate it

Comment: You seem to have a hardcoded `path` - you need to consider where you want your files to end up on your server when it is published. Where that can be will vary depending on your hosting technology - there's no need to look for a serilog-specific answer